# Finding base $B'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am given
$$
        B = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 2 \\
        -2 & 2 & -1 \\
        -1 & 2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
How can I find a base $B'$, so that for all vectors $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ applies $x + [x]_B + [x]_{B′} = 0$?

(meaning: if I take coordinates of a vector $x$ and add it to coordinates of this vector in map of base $B$ and in map of base $B'$, then I have to get the 0 vector)

Comment: What do you mean by $[x]_B$ where $B$ is a matrix?

Comment: Those are coordinates of vector $x$ in map of base $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I got it right* ("base" $B$ means basis formed by the columns of $B$), you want to find $B':=C^{-1}$ such that
$$\tag{1}
x+B^{-1}x+Cx=0
$$
for all $x$ (this, of course, requires that such a $C$ must be invertible). But (1) is equivalent to $I+B^{-1}+C=0$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix, so we have 
$$
C=-(I+B^{-1})=\frac{1}{7}\pmatrix{-3&5&-3\\3&-5&-4\\-2&1&-9}
$$
and hence
$$
B'=C^{-1}=\pmatrix{7&6&-5\\5&3&-3\\-1&-1&0}.
$$

Comment: Yes, you've got it right. Nice, thanks / Nádhera, díky, Pavle.

Comment: You are welcome / Neni zac :)